# react проблема после обновления

Tags: reactjs, redux

Если такой компанент, это ProductItem, то есть когда я нажимаю на предмет в интернет магазине, у меня открывается страница с этим предметом, то есть потробная информация о товаре, так вот в целом оно работает, но если эту страницу обновить, то я получаю ошибку TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'image'), по сути похоже что массив оказывается пустым, но почему я не знаю

```
    const params = useParams()
    const products = useSelector(state => state.products.productsArr)
    const item = products.filter((item) => item.id === params.id);
    const obj = item[0];
    const goBack = () => {
        props.history.goBack();
    }
    useEffect(() => {

    }, [])
    return (
        <div className='product-item'>
            <div>
                <img src={obj.image} alt={obj.name}/>
            </div>
            <div className='product-info'>
                <h2>{obj.name}</h2>
                <h4>Price: <strong>{obj.price}</strong></h4>
                <div className='descItems'>
                    {!obj.description && <div>no description</div>}
                    {obj.description && <div>{obj.description}</div>}
                </div>
                <div className='product-buttons'>

                    <div><button onClick={goBack} className='btn btn-success me-2'>add to cart</button></div>
                    <div><button onClick={goBack} className='btn btn-info me-2'>back</button></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: после обновления эта строка становится пустым массивом const products = useSelector(state => state.products.productsArr), ну то есть products = []

Comment: я попробовал это     const products = useSelector(state => state.products.productsArr)
    if (products.length === 0) {
        fetchAllItems()
    } но не помогает. fetchAllItems должен был положить объекты из api в products, но возможно из-за асинхронности он либо не успевает, либо просто не делает